# Delimitershortfall in align environment

Tags: amsmath, align, delimiters

Can you explain why the `\delimitershortfall` cannot be modified inside a `align` environment?

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \delimitershortfall -1pt     \left(\left((x)\right)\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
    \delimitershortfall = -1pt     \left(\left((x)\right)\right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image: Example]

In the first case the outer parenthesis are larger, as expected. But in the second case, the new value of `\delimitershortfall` seems ignored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens in `align` is that every cell is in a group, like `{<formula>}`, so when the formula is eventually typeset, the change to `\delimiterfactor` has been forgotten. How to get out of this problem? A workaround would be to execute the change after the group has ended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dsf}{\delimitershortfall=-1pt }

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\aftergroup\dsf \left(\left((x)\right)\right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The group is visible in lines 2074–2086 of `amsmath.sty` in the definition of `\align@preamble`; basically, every cell is typeset in a box using

```
$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$
```

where `\m@th` is used for neutralizing possible settings of `\mathsurround` and `##` stands for the actual contents of the alignment cell. In our case, the input with `\aftergroup\dsf` is equivalent to use

```
$\m@th\displaystyle{\left(\left((x)\right)\right)}\dsf$
```

which causes TeX to use the desired value.

Note that TeX uses only one value for `\delimitershortfall`, the one current when math mode is exited and the math list is converted into a horizontal list.

See, for example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}{\left(\left((x)\right)\right)}
\newcommand{\testa}{\delimitershortfall=-1pt \test}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\test$

$\displaystyle\testa$

$\displaystyle\test\testa$

$\displaystyle\test{\testa}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, in the third and fourth lines, only one value of `\delimitershortfall` is used: in the third line -1pt for both tests, in the fourth line the default 5pt for both.

Thus you won't be able to change `\delimitershortfall` for two parts of the same equation or alignment cell.

Comment: Thanks ! What I retain is that I cannot use different values `\delimitershortfall` in the same equation. Also I found confusing that it is the last value of the parameter which is use.

Comment: @PaulPichaureau The same happens with many parameters for formulas, like `\relpenalty`. It even happens for assignment of fonts to families (see p. 153 in the TeXbook). You can “cheat“ by using `align` and `<formula1>&<formula2>`, where the subformulas can have distinct values of `\delimitershortfall` (with the above trick). However I don't see why you'd want to do it.

Comment: I need to define the probability of an event: `P((X=5) \cap A)` In this case, I would like that the outer parenthesis is slightly larger than the inner one. But I don't want to modify `\delimitershortfall` for the whole document.

Comment: @PaulPichaureau `P\bigl((X=5\cap A\bigr)` is the way to go. Don't use `\left` or `\right` for every delimiter.

Comment: It is what I've done. The interesting point with `\left\right` is the variation of size... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\begin{align}
    \global\delimitershortfall=-1pt     
    \left(\left((x)\right)\right)
\end{align}
```

or

```
{\delimitershortfall=-1pt
\begin{align} 
    \left(\left((x)\right)\right)
\end{align}}
```

the contents of `align` is set inside a group

Comment: I don't want use these solutions, since my goal is to write a macro to change `\delimitershortfall` inside a formula. See my comment to the preceding answer. Thanks anyway !