# How can I make \left and \right consider additional sizes?

Tags: delimiters, resize

As I understand it, when a delimiter is marked `\left` or `\right`, its size will be chosen from among the available sizes. Suppose I define some new sizes, how can I make `\left` and `\right` use them when appropriate?

---

To make this concrete, let’s say I have defined some custom sizes for delimiters:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\bbig#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.88}[0.77]{\Big#1}}}}
\def\biig#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.95}[0.88]{\Big#1}}}}
\def\Biig#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.95}[0.88]{\bigg#1}}}}
\def\biigg#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.95}[0.9]{\Bigg#1}}}}
\def\Biigg#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.05}[1.1]{\Bigg#1}}}}
```

Then I can use them like this:

```
$$
\Biigg\{ \Bigg\{ \biigg\{ \bigg\{ \Biig\{ \Big\{ \biig\{ \bbig\{ \big\{ \{
$$
```

Which produces:

[image: Bracket sizes]

So far so good. These are the sizes I want, and I can use them with any delimiter. (To use them outside of math mode we’d need to put `{\hbox{$...$}}` in the definitions.) Throw in the -l and -r versions with `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`, and we’re off and running.

However, I would rather use `\left` and `\right` instead of manually specifying delimiter sizes. How can I make `\left` and `\right` aware of my custom sizes, so they will be chosen when appropriate?

(Alternatively, is there a better way to do this?)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120957/delimitershortfall-in-align-environment.

Comment: Essentially the "intended" way is to modify the definition in the font file. But you can probably hack them together with TeX macro programming, with lots lots of limitations.

Comment: Very similar [math mode - delimiters with exact size - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67934/delimiters-with-exact-size) except that this question asks for finer discrete jump instead of continuous jump.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that answers your question but I personally use a different approach.

I created new macros `\fleft` and `\fright` with an optional parameters, which stand for *fixed left* and *fixed right*. With a non-empty argument in use, the size of brackets is "fixed". Otherwise, it is the equivalent to the regular `\leftX...\rightX`.

For instance, in the code below, `\fleft(...\fright)` (without arguments) adapts bracket dimensions to a size of the matrix. On the other hand, with non-empty arguments `\fleft[3]\{...\fright[3]\}`, brackets are fixed.

The *factor* when equal or larger than 3 corresponds to any next big bracket "bigger" than `\BigglX...\BiggrX`. The interval is 0.5, hence providing `3` and `3.5` would typeset brackets similar to `\biggglX...\bigggrX` and `\BigggrX...\BiggglX`, respectively.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\fleft{O{}}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{\notblank{#1}{\mathopen\bBigg@{#1}}{\left}}{\left}}
\NewDocumentCommand\fright{O{}}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{\notblank{#1}{\mathopen\bBigg@{#1}}{\right}}{\right}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[
    \fleft(
        \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\s\\e\end{bmatrix}
        X
    \fright)
    \fleft[3]\{
        \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\s\\e\end{bmatrix}
        X
    \fright[3]\}
\]
\end{document}
```